# Why does Finder search not find my .c files?

Tags: macos, finder, spotlight

My goal is, that the **finder search** finds .c files that have the search keywords in it.  It seems to work for others but not for me:

[image]

but searching for `main` doesn't yield any results:

[image]

What do I need to change/fix to get it to work?

Comment: What makes you think that Spotlight doesn't already do that? I just run some tests here and Spotlight found text in .c/.h files without problems.

Comment: I would have to agree with patrix. I did a search for a string contained within my C source code, and my Spotlight search showed them in the list. Is it possible that you don't have Developer indexed in your Spotlight settings?

Comment: You both are totally right. I thought, Spotlight behaves the same as the finder search. But, apparently it doesn't. My problem is, that the finder search doesn't find text inside .c files for example. (I will modify the question)

Comment: Uhh, Finder search on .c/.h works as expected for me as well (see http://d.pr/i/X0iH), it's based on the same meta data as Spotlight anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. That's what I'd like to get, too. http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=efed762 and http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=c2c791a

Comment: I've edited your question to reflect this, feel free to rollback or improve if needed.

Comment: Have you installed Xcode?

Comment: @Mark Yes I have.

Answer (score 1):

See attached image:

[image: C_search]

When I search with the parameters Kind:C source code and for the term Bootstrap, I am able to locate all of my C files that contain that string.

Is this the functionality that you are wanting that you don't have?

Comment: It certainly would be better than nothing, but not even that works. My goal is to have the identical behaviour like Spotlight but just for the current folder (i have the option to search in the current folder activated).